# Convert dates into weeks

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert the continuous date into weeks , `saturday should be the week ending`
Eample:

```
2/27/2015       3/6/2015          3/13/2015      3/20/2015
```

here I am giving more info on my requirement so that you can understand easily.

I have a datetime field in my db lets say Date2. I need to group this date into weeks in `mm/ dd/ yyyy.` 
lets take an example my `date2` start like `1/1/2015` to `20/1/2015`.

```
1/1/2015-3/1/2015 this range displayed as   3/1/2015,
4/1/2015-10/1/2015 ----------------------- 10/1/2015,
11/1/2015-17/1/2015 ---------------------- 17/1/2015,
18/1/2015-24/1/2015 ---------------------  24/1/2015
```

Comment: Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week (Sunday is the first day of your week).

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are asking, so I will guess. Please forgive if I guess wrong.

Let us say you have an arbitrary `DATETIME` column named `Date2` , and you wish to produce the `DATE` of the Sunday immediately preceding that value.  In other words, you wish to figure out the week in which the `DATETIME` occurs.

You can do that like this:

```
 FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(Date2) -MOD(TO_DAYS(Date2) -1, 7))
```

So, if you have a Sales table with `customer_id`, `Date2`, and `sale`, you can summarize by week like this:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(Date2) -MOD(TO_DAYS(Date) -1, 7)) week_beginning,
       COUNT(*) num_transactions,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) num_customers,
       SUM(sale) total_sales 
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(Date2) -MOD(TO_DAYS(Date) -1, 7))
```

This will show the date of the Sunday that begins each calendar week. If you want the Saturday that ends each calendar week, use this instead.

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(Date2) -MOD(TO_DAYS(Date) -1, 7))
          + INTERVAL 6 DAY week_ending,
       COUNT(*) num_transactions, ...
```

I have written this up in detail here: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

You can